# Apache 2.4 on Centos 7 not taking SSLCipherSuite changes

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I'm trying to disable the CBC suits, but for some reason, no matter how much I change the SSLCipherSuites option, there isn't any change happening in apache!

When I enable or disable TLS1.1 for example, it changes fine. But when I change

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:+HIGH:!ADH:!EXP:!SSLv2:!SSLv3:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!NULL:!aNULL
```

to

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

Nothing changes. I even tried putting just one:

```
SSLCipherSuite "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
```

But still I get that there are CBC ciphers active! How do I change them?

```
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
```

Comment: My guess is that the setting you apply does not affect the part of the server you've tested. For example you might apply a setting for a specific virtual host but then test against an IP address or don't use SNI to access the host. Unfortunately nothing is known about your full setup and how you've exactly tested, so this is just an educated guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

[Apparently](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/ciphers.html), there is really no string you can use to disable "CBC" ciphers specifically. You can use the following instead:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!RSA:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384
```

Comment: CBC ciphers are still appearing.. :(

Comment: What tool are you using to test this?

Comment: nmap and ssllabs.com

Comment: nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p ip

Comment: Updated my answer.